# Flutter Upgrade: After updating latest version of flutter previous function not working

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I have tried this function in flutter version v0.5.1 and it is working fine, no issue. After I have updated to the latest version v0.8.4 I get the exception below.

> ExcceptionDatainheritFromWidgetOfExactType(_LocalizationsScope) was
>   called before ProfileScreen.initState() completed.

```
        When an inherited widget changes, for example if the value of Theme.of() changes, its dependent widgets are rebuilt. If the dependent widget's reference to the inherited widget is in a constructor or an initState() method, then the rebuilt dependent widget will not reflect the changes in the inherited widget.
        Typically references to to inherited widgets should occur in widget build() methods. Alternatively, initialization based on inherited widgets can be placed in the didChangeDependencies method, which is called after initState and whenever the dependencies change thereafter.

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    makeRequest();
  }
  Future<DataModel> makeRequest() async {
    _onLoading();

    http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.encodeFull(getProfile),
        headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});

   /// json data calling.....
  }

  void _onLoading() {

    if (loadCheck) {
        showDialog(
            context: context,
            barrierDismissible: false,
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return new Dialog(
                // progress dialog calling );
            }
        );
    } else {
      Navigator.pop(context);
    }
  }
```

Comment: I have found solution, reason for the error i am using show dialog in initState() method after change code slightly using    this line  new Future.delayed(Duration.zero,() =>_onLoading());  working fine

Comment: Please consider posting this as an answer (and subsequently accepting it), so that it can be of possible usefulness to others in the future (comments may be deleted in any time).

Answer (score -1):

You need the context from

```
@override Widget build(BuildContext context) {
....
....
makeRequest()
```

method paste after Widget build... and pass parameter (context) into parenthesis like this

```
makeRequest(context)
```

and again

```
_onLoading(context)
```

and use

```
showDialog(
        context: context, //The context from Widget Build(BuildContext context)...
```

It is a common problem if you use Provider and InitState.